# RequestsLibrary - how to send both data and file in the same POST request

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, automated-tests, robotframework

I have the following Python script for uploading a `file` along with some `payload`. I tried to run on a robot framework, but I received the response output as `Bad request`

Python Script

```
import requests

url = "https://api.company.net/certificates/upload/0b36f50c-8458-4478-b83e-cfb99wef9c73"

payload={'flowChunkNumber': '1',
         'flowChunkSize': '1048576',
         'flowCurrentChunkSize': '25020',
         'flowTotalSize': '25020',
         'flowIdentifier': '25020-test_certificate_reportpdf',
         'flowFilename': 'test_certificate_report.pdf',
         'flowRelativePath': 'test_certificate_report.pdf',
         'flowTotalChunks': '1'}
files=[
  ('file',('test_certificate_report.pdf',open('/C:/RobotFramework/DATA_Test/support_files/test_certificate_report.pdf','rb'),'application/pdf'))
]
headers = {
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            'Cookie': 'PHPSESSID=7ios0o98lbljrdrlvfk0456rujh'
          }
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.text)
```

The following is the `Robot Framework` test script that I wrote, which is giving the error-

TEST_Case Flow

```
*** Variables ***        
        &{headers}    Create Dictionary    X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest
        ${email_admin}   email@company.com
        ${password}    password123
        ${base_url}    https://api.company.net

*** Test Cases ***
 Login
        &{auth_dict}=    Create Dictionary    email    ${email}    password    ${password}
        Create Session    api    ${base_url}    verify=True
        ${test_uri}    Set Variable    /session/login
        ${response}    POST On Session    api    ${test_uri}    json=${auth_dict}    headers=&{headers}

  Upload_File
        &{payload}    Create Dictionary    flowChunkNumber    1    flowChunkSize    1048576    flowCurrentChunkSize    25020    flowTotalSize    25020    flowIdentifier    25020-test_certificate_reportpdf    flowFilename    test_certificate_report.pdf    flowRelativePath    test_certificate_report.pdf    flowTotalChunks 1
        &{file}    Create Dictionary    file=${file_location}/test_certificate_report.pdf
        ${test_uri}    Set Variable    https://api.company.net/certificates/upload/0b36f50c-8458-4478-b83e-cfb99wef9c73
        ${response}    POST On Session    api    ${test_uri}    data=&{payload}    files=&{file}    headers=&{headers}
```

> `HTTPError: 400` Client Error: Bad Request for url:
> https://api.company.net/certificates/upload/0b36f50c-8458-4478-b83e-cfb99wef9c73

Is there a better way to pass both `data` and `file` in the same POST request in Robot Framework?

Thanks in advance.

---*Update*--

The uploading file is a blank pdf file for the test. No data should be read from the file.

Comment: Is there a reason you're calling `POST On Session` with `headers=&{headers}`, but not `headers=${headers}`?

Comment: Because &{headers} is a dictionary.

Comment: @BoburMeliev that is absolutely so, and it's a convention to use the & symbol when _defining_  a dict variable. But when _using_ its value, the & instructs the framework to unpack it to key:value pairs, which leads to unexpected results. Which is a possible cause for what OP is seeing as misbehavior.

Answer (score 0):

Replace third line with this

```
${file}=    Get File For Streaming Upload    ${file_location}/test_certificate_report.pdf
```

Pass file as value of `data` and JSON payload as of `json`.

```
${response}    POST On Session    api    ${test_uri}    json=${payload}    data=${file}    headers=&{headers}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. I'm facing the following error.
`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: Can you paste whole test case otherwise it's not clear which keyword is failing.

Comment: I have updated the test script as asked for.

Answer (score 0):

```
${file_pdf}         app/file/file_upload.pdf

Send Post Request With Upload File
    [Arguments]  ${url}     ${payload}   ${files}    ${token}=${token_admin}
    ${header}=  create dictionary   Authorization=Bearer ${token}
    Create Session      test     ${base_url}
    ${response}=    POST On Session    test    ${url}    headers=${header}     files=${files}      data=${payload}
    [Return]   ${response}

Test Upload file Success
    ${json_data}=    Evaluate    str(${json_data).replace("'",'"')
    ${file_data}  Get File For Streaming Upload    ${file_pdf}
    ${files}  Create Dictionary  files=${file_data}
    ${data}=    Create Dictionary    req_body=${json_data}
    ${response}=    Send Post Request With Upload File      ${endpoint}     ${data}       ${files}
```

Send Post Request With Upload File is a keyword to send data,
when using Get File For Streaming Upload, We don't need Content-type

It will correspond to the python request below:

```
url = "http://localhost/api/xxx"

payload = {'req_body': '{"name":"xxx","password":"1111"}
files=[
  ('files',('file_upload.pdf',open('app/file/file_upload.pdf','rb'),'application/pdf'))
]
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJ....'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
```